# Github Actions- expression function to set environment variable

Tags: github-actions

I had written below Github Actions where I am unable to set URL in the workflow graph.

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with running Fortify scans using ScanCentral into Fortify SSC

name: Namelink Scan

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      choice:
        type: choice
        description: Please select the project to scan
        options:
        - Factorysite
        - HouseSite
env:
    Factorysite: "https://company.com"
    HouseSite: "https://house.com"

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "Scan"
  Scan:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: windows-latest
    environment:
      name: Test
      url: ${{ format('env.{0}', inputs.choice) }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

In the environment section, I mentioned the environments as below

```
environment:
      name: Test
      url: ${{ format('env.{0}', inputs.choice) }}
```

Expected Output to show URL in workflow graph.

[Expected Output with URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4a0r.png)

Actual Output with warning in workflow Graph.

[Actual Output without URL link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OUkq.png)

Receiving below warning which I cant to fix.

```
Annotations
1 warning
Scan
Environment URL 'env.Factorysite' is not a valid http(s) URL, so it will not be shown as a link in the workflow graph.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the given code example

```
environment:
  name: Test
  url: ${{ format('env.{0}', inputs.choice) }}
```

The `url` property value is evaluated to either `env.Factorysite` or `env.HouseSite` **string** depending on provided `choice`. Take note it's a string (not a value of an evaluated string). So you will not get the appropriate `url` value at runtime but the name of the environment property holding the URL value. In other words, the code written is not equivalent to (what you expect):

```
environment:
  name: Test
  url: ${{ env.Factorysite }}
```

In this example, the value of the `url` property will be evaluated at workflow runtime to the value of the environment variable (`https://company.com` in your case). So far so good. Now we want to join the approaches to get the value of the proper URL at runtime based on provided `choice`. Since [env context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#env-context) is an object we can refer to its properties using the array access operator (`[]`) to get the given property value:

```
environment:
  name: Test
  url: ${{ env[inputs.choice] }}
```

This way you can populate the expected value of the `environment.url` and get it properly displayed in the workflow visualization graph.

Comment: Klopotek: Thanks for wonderful explanation. It works like a charm